# traversing a tree in a different way

Tags: java, recursion, tree, iteration

I currently have done this so far: I tried to traverse the tree so that I can add up everything underneath a person.

Every person has int points, and an ArrayList of Friends. Imagine everyone in the tree is in a team. So the biggest team is the whole tree, but B also leads a sub team of D and E, while C leads F.

I want to calculate the biggest average of points per team. My current code tries to loop through the tree iteratively, but I have no idea how to get the sub totals of each team instead of the whole team. Do I need to do this recursively?
What I really need is a way to trasverse this tree on the basis of teams.
I would like the average points of a team with A,B,C,D,E,F and a team of B,D,E and the team with C and F.

```
       A
     /   \
    B     C
  /  \    |     
 D    E   F
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person a = new Person(5);
    Person b = new Person(3);
    Person c = new Person(2);
    ArrayList<Person> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

    list1.add(b);
    list1.add(c);
    a.friends = list1;

    mostPoints(a);
}


public static Employee mostPoints(Person start) {
    int topFriend = 1;

    for (Person person: start.friends) {
        if (person.friends.size() > 1) {
            topFriend++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(topFriend);

    int total = 0;
    for (Person under: start.friends) {
        total = total + under.points;
    }

    return total / start.friends.size();
}
```

Comment: You only need recursion if you need to count the friends of friends of friends of friends etc, but you need to be careful that not to get stuck in a recursion loop because the friends will have each other in their lists.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, but least efficient way: Traverse the tree, average each node (invoke `mostPoints` method), put it in an array, and take its biggest.

```
public class StackOverflowSolve {

private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

public int slove(Person person) {
    dfs(person);
    return list.stream().reduce(Integer::max).get();
}

public void dfs(Person person) {
    if (person == null) {
        return;
    }
    list.add(average(person));
    if (person.friends != null && person.friends.size() > 0) {
        person.friends.forEach(child -> {
            dfs(child);
        });
    }
}

public int average(Person person) {
    return sum(person) / teamSize(person);
}

public int sum(Person person) {
    if (person == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (person.friends == null || person.friends.size() == 0) {
        return person.points;
    }
    int friendPonits = 0;
    for (Person friend : person.friends) {
        friendPonits += sum(friend);
    }
    return friendPonits + person.points;
}

public int teamSize(Person person) {

    if (person == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (person.friends == null || person.friends.size() == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    int friendSize = 0;
    for (Person friend : person.friends) {
        friendSize += teamSize(friend);
    }
    return friendSize + 1;
}


private static class Person {
    public int points;
    public List<Person> friends;
}
```

}

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean in your code, because I want to get the average of each team and sub team, and for my example tree, there should be 3 teams. Surely I could only get the average of the sub teams right and not the average of the entire tree team?